# Protobuf causes segfault on init when compiled with Clang

Tags: c++, clang, protocol-buffers

After switching from GCC to LLVM for a codebase which relies on Protobuf, I keep getting a segfault during "initialization". No Protobuf r/w is being executed when the exception occurs.

The stack trace looks like this:

```
__dynamic_cast (@__dynamic_cast:13)
google::protobuf::Message const* google::protobuf::internal::down_cast<google::protobuf::Message const*, google::protobuf::MessageLite const>(google::protobuf::MessageLite const*) (@google::protobuf::Message const* google::protobuf::internal::down_cast<google::protobuf::Message const*, google::protobuf::MessageLite const>(google::protobuf::MessageLite const*):25)
google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(google::protobuf::MessageLite const&) (@google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(google::protobuf::MessageLite const&):12)
google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromArray(void const*, int) (@google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromArray(void const*, int):68)
google::protobuf::EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add(void const*, int) (@google::protobuf::EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add(void const*, int):23)
google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int) (@google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int):17)
protobuf_google_2fprotobuf_2fany_2eproto::AddDescriptorsImpl() (@protobuf_google_2fprotobuf_2fany_2eproto::AddDescriptorsImpl():9)
__pthread_once_slow (@__pthread_once_slow:58)
___lldb_unnamed_symbol7928 (@___lldb_unnamed_symbol7928:24)
```

and the method in which it occurs is in `protobuf/message.cc`:

```
void Message::MergeFrom(const Message& from) {
  auto* class_to = GetClassData();
  auto* class_from = from.GetClassData();
  auto* merge_to_from = class_to ? class_to->merge_to_from : nullptr;
  if (class_to == nullptr || class_to != class_from) {
    merge_to_from = [](Message* to, const Message& from) {
      ReflectionOps::Merge(from, to);
    };
  }
  merge_to_from(this, from);
}
```

at `from.GetClassData()`.

I've built Protobuf locally (Ubuntu 20.04) using various configurations with similar results. The most successful configuration being:

```
./configure CC=clang CXX="clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++" --disable-shared
```

I've also seen instructions online suggesting to build Protobuf using `libc++`, in which case my code fails to link.

Comment: What if the bug is actually on line 10191 but isn't expressed in a visible manner until half an hour later inside an innocent call to protobuf?

Comment: I reduced the executable code path to `int main() { return 0; }`, but still linking protobuf - which causes the same error as before.